# Pass data to different activity but redirect to another

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm creating an appointment booking app where users can see their details at the very end. I'm passing data using `bundles`.

So, is it possible for me to pass data to last page (consider it as 4th page),
and the intent redirect to next page (that would be 2nd page) `simultaneously`.

Answer (score 0):

Use sharedPreferences to save data. You can open the same file and access the data in any activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `public static` variable in the first activity like

```
public static String name;
```

and store your data in it

In the 4th activity you can access that variable like

```
FirstActivityName.name;
```

Comment: did you store it after the user enters the data. What is the issue?

Answer (score -1):

> startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) when you expecting some back data from other activity then, this method is useful.

```
         Intent intent1 = new Intent(FirstScreen.this,SecondScreen.class);
 
           intent1.putExtra("first_name",edt1.getText().toString());
           intent1.putExtra("last_name",edt2.getText().toString());
           intent1.putExtra("date_of_birth",edt3.getText().toString());
              
           startActivityForResult(intent1,1);
```

> To receive data from an activity, we can use either Intent.getStringExtra(key)

```
        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
 
        String first = intent2.getStringExtra("first_name");
        String last = intent2.getStringExtra("last_name");
        String dob = intent2.getStringExtra("date_of_birth");
```

hope this will help you

Comment: tried above method, Value came as "null" through intent.